# Spyder: What's the best python IDE for OpenCV 3. Spyder output window becomes unresponsive

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, spyder

I am beginner and using spyder for my openCV 3 python project. The programs run fine but when the output window is launched it becomes unresponsive after the program ends(given some condition like 'esc' or 'Q' key) and I have to restart the kernel each and every time to run the code.
I am using OpenCV 3.1 and python 3.5.

EDIT: I am using mac with macOS 10.13.

Comment: I use Spyder too but have never had any problems with the IDE itself. There's probably something wrong with your code. Post your code here so we can evaluate it.

Comment: I am using the documentation example code. The code runs fine, it pops up the window normally and does what it is supposed to. But the window doesn't close after the termination condition or when I manually stop the kernel.

Comment: This does not sound like an issue with Spyder. Link the code so we can see if we can replicate the issue.

Comment: @ShawnMathew Use any piece of code from the documentation page. All have the same behavior. https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d2e/tutorial_py_image_display.html

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate your issue after I hit any other key besides those being handled by the code. For example, hitting the ESC key or the S Key worked perfectly fine, but any other key crashed the GUI.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\mathesn\Downloads\IMAG1825.jpg",0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
    #save file here
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To avoid this, add code to handle other keypresses as well by just adding an `else` block.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\mathesn\Downloads\IMAG1825.jpg",0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
    #save file here
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Since all key events are now handled, the GUI shouldn't crash

Comment: My problem is the secondary UI window that opens doesn't close on its own and it freezes even if I press the required key like 'esc' or 's'. The code does stop running in the spyder.

Comment: what secondary UI window? the only one that opens is the 'image' window

Comment: Yes the image window. Sorry for not clarifying. By secondary I meant other than the terminal output window.

Comment: Have you tried the adding the last `else` block. I've tested that and it closes the 'image' window without freezing on other keypresses

Comment: Yeah I tried. Still it doesn't close the window on it's own. Still it shows the cursor in waiting position while hovering on the window. Either I have to restart the kernel or run another program which works for most of the times but sometimes  it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, seems it's Spyder's interior problem on Mac OS. I ran the python script in console and it worked fine. (Some people say Pycharm doesn't have this issue, but I didn't verify it.)